# Include table name in column from select wildcard sql

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to include table name in the returned column if I use wildcard to select all columns from tables?

To explain it further.  Suppose I want to join two tables and both tables have the column name “name” and many other columns.  I want to use wildcard to select all columns and not explicitly specifying each column name in the select.

```
Select *
From 
TableA a,
TableB b
Where 
a.id = b.id
```

Instead of seeing two column with same name "name", could I write a sql to return one column name as "a.name" (or TableA.name) and one as "b.name"(or TableB.name) without explicitly putting the column name in select?

I would prefer a solution for mssql but other database could be a reference too.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you will need to explicitely use a column alias. Using `*` in production code is bad coding style anyway.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name.  I am just doing some casual sql select on my dbartisan and suddenly dream if it is doable, but seems like it will stay only in my dream :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `select a.*, '    ', b.* from T1 a, T2 b`  to make it more visible where columns from T1 end and columns from T2 begin.

Comment: Thanks Stoleg, I think it will help

Answer (score 1):

You are basically joining two tables on the ID field, so you will only see one column labeled "ID", not two, because you are asking to see only those records where the ID is the same in table a and table b: they share the same id.

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  I re-read my question and agreed using "ID" as example does not make sense.  I have modified my question to use column "name" instead of "id".  Thanks again.

Comment: There are workarounds like creating temp tables with just the columns you want in them that would let you alias the two ID columns. the problem (as I see it) is you would then get duplicate columns anyway.
Unless you have a ton of columns, it's a good idea to explicitly name the columns in your query. For one thing, you reduce db usage time if you don't need to return all columns; more importantly for you, it lets you assign aliases to your columns.

Answer (score -1):

Try ...

```
SELECT 'TableA' AS 'Table', A.* FROM TableA A
WHERE A.id IN (SELECT id FROM TableB)
UNION
SELECT 'TableB' AS 'Table', B.* FROM TableB B
WHERE B.id IN (SELECT id FROM TableA)
ORDER BY id, [Table]
```